# CommandError during installing Openstack

Tags: openstack

I was installing Openstack via devstack in ubuntu 16.04, it's running well for 20min until the error posted. I am not sure it's regarding compression or memory, it's hard to google the answer according to the error message. Anyone can take a look?

```
    1645 static files copied to '/opt/stack/horizon/static'.
+lib/horizon:init_horizon:151              DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=openstack_dashboard.settings
+lib/horizon:init_horizon:151              django-admin compress --force
Found 'compress' tags in:
/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/templates/horizon/_scripts.html
/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/templates/horizon/_conf.html
/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/templates/_stylesheets.html
Compressing... CommandError: An error occurred during rendering /opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/templates/_stylesheets.html: Error parsing block:
@import "headers/headers";
@import "table/table";
@import "charts/chart-tooltip";
@import "charts/pie-chart";
@import "action-list/action-list";
@import "modal-wait-spinner/modal-wait-spinner";
@import "metadata/metadata";
@import "magic-search/magic-search";
@import "table/hz-dynamic-table";


on line 56 of framework/widgets/widgets.scss
imported from line 56 of framework/framework.scss
imported from line 6 of dashboard/scss/horizon.scss
imported from line 1 of u'string:2330f72e9784e4fd:\n    // My Themes\n@import "/themes/default/variables";\n\n// Horizon\n@import "/dashboard/scss/horizon.'
Traceback:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scss/compiler.py", line 374, in manage_children
self._manage_children_impl(rule, scope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scss/compiler.py", line 385, in _manage_children_impl
block = UnparsedBlock(rule, c_lineno, c_property, c_codestr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scss/rule.py", line 342, in __init__
self.header = BlockHeader.parse(prop, has_contents=bool(unparsed_contents))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scss/rule.py", line 252, in parse
prop, re.I)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 141, in match
return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 249, in _compile
p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 576, in compile
code = _code(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 561, in _code
_compile(code, p.data, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 151, in _compile
_compile(code, av[1], flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 192, in _compile
_compile(code, av, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 132, in _compile
_compile(code, av[2], flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 107, in _compile
_compile_charset(av, flags, code, fixup, fixes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 232, in _compile_charset
flags & SRE_FLAG_UNICODE):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 274, in _optimize_charset
r = range(av[0], av[1]+1)
MemoryError:
+lib/horizon:init_horizon:1                exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:487                  local r=1
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:491                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:497                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:383               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:499                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:500                  echo 'Error on exit'
    Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:501                  generate-subunit 1474274293 3005 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:502                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:505                  /root/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
```

World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2016-09-19-092821.txt for details
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                  exit 1

Comment: A memory error means that your program has ran out of memory.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

Comment: Issue resolved by adding more memory. Thanks!